# Laravel 8 - ссылка из Inertia на страницу входа и регистрации

Tags: laravel

Установил Laravel8 и пакет Jetstream, решил использовать Inertia, всё по документации. Главная страница по стандарту генерируется на Blade, Регистрация и авторизация на пакете Livewire. Решил создать свою главную страницу на Inertia и столкнулся с проблемой. При указании ссылки на стандартную страницу авторизации или регистрации они открываются в модальном окне, а не осуществляется переход к ним. После несения данных, всё равно остаётся модельное окно, только при перезагрузке страницы переходит в нормальный вид. И эта проблема только со стандартными страницами которые идут в пакете. Как исправить проблему[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]